# The point is chosen by luck inside of a circle of radius 1. What is the expectation that its distance will be near the center?

Tags: probability

First I found the probability of the point being inside the smaller circle which is $$P(X<x)=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\pi}{\pi}=\frac{1}{4}; \quad \frac{1}{4}\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}$$ 
Now, to find the expectancy I first have to to the derivative of $F(x)$ to find $f(x)$, But If I do that I immediately get 0, therefore the expectancy is zero.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "near?" Do you wish to be within a certain distance of the center? Are we looking for the expected distance from the center (expectation/mean/average) or a probability?

Comment: We are looking for the expected distance to the center of the circle

Comment: There should be an $x$ in the formula for $P(X<x).$

Comment: I know but I'm not sure how to put it inside...

Comment: wesewx If as it seems radius of big circle is 1, then radius of small circle is x so P(X<x) is $(\pi x^2)/\pi=x^2.$ Then your density is deriv of that or $2x.$ Then multiply this by $x$ and integrate from 0 to 1 for expected distance.

Comment: Ok, but how come I can not just make a conclusion that instead of x my radius of the smaller circle is 1/2?

Comment: I got it now tnx @coffeemath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed that the radius of the smaller circle is $\frac 12$, presumably because it looks that way in the diagram and correctly calculated the chance the point is within a circle of radius $\frac 12$.  The problem does not state that the radius of the smaller circle is $\frac 12$.  You should take the radius of the small circle as $x$, then find the probability that the point is within the small circle.  That will give you $F(x)$, which will depend on $x$.  You will then be able to take the derivative to find $f(x)$.  You need to replace the $\frac 14\pi$ in the numerator with the area of the small circle of radius $x$

Comment: Yea I got it  now, I just assumed directly that the radius needs to be 1/2 for the second small circle ..